# convenience initialization

Tags: c#, constructor, initialization

Is there a convenience process to assign the value of Property "Caller" in the constructor below to a single line?

```
public partial class SecurityPrompt : Form {

    Form1 Caller { get; set; }

    public SecurityPrompt(Form1 _caller)  {
        Caller = _caller;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't `Caller = _caller;` already a single line?

Comment: You want to get it down from 2 lines to 1?

Comment: I think he's asking if there's something like C++'s initialization lists (which there isn't in C#)

Comment: It's considered bad practice for a child form to hold onto an instance of the parent form; you really shouldn't be doing this in the first place.  You'd be better off using events to allow actions in the child form to affect it's parent form.

Comment: Thanks @Servy , I have modified the code to add event listeners to the now public buttons on the child controls.

Comment: @sammarcow You should virtually never have child controls, such as buttons, be public.  Child controls of a Form are the responsibility of that Form to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [object initializer syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx), but that creates the constructor and then assigns public properties. You'd have to refactor your constructor here if you wanted to use that.

Using object initializer:

> The compiler processes object initializers by first accessing the default instance constructor, and then by processing the member initializations.

If you do use this your property won't be set until after the constructor is created. So if you call functions in the constructor expecting your property to be there it won't. Keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a convenience process to assign the value of Property "Caller" in the constructor below to a single line?

No.  Your current syntax is the "standard" way to assign a property within a constructor.  There is no shortcut (like [C++'s initialization lists](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/101-constructor-initialization-lists/) or similar).  In C#, it is always done inline in the constructor body.